# makefile and perl

Tags: perl, makefile

i'm looking for an improved makefile version where it has makefile/perl combined together.

Is there anything like this?

Comment: I really don't understand what you're asking for.  Could you give a hypothetical example?

Comment: how do i avoid limitations with the number of characters for command line execution? additionaly need to do some fancy string manipulations for variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What are you trying to accomplish?  Perl is a tool that does a lot of things, and make is a tool that does some things, and there's some overlap.

Maybe you're looking for [pmake](http://p3rl.org/pmake)?

Comment: "and there's some overlap": calling executables:)

Answer (score 2):

There are also alternatives to [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) written in Perl, such as [PBS](http://p3rl.org/%2aPBS%2a).

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is [makepp](http://makepp.sourceforge.net/). If you update the question with specific things you'd like to do, I can probably say whether or not makepp will help.